# Reusable UITableViewCells repeating content

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm having a very common problem that I don't know how to fix for myself, even after reading a bunch of similar posts, since making my cells non-reusable is **not an option** (the app slows down immensely).

**The Problem**

When I have 6 or more cells (maximum of 16), the contents of the first 5 cells begin appearing in all of the other cells when I scroll to them.

Though I am using reusable cells, why are the contents of my cells not being refreshed with new data that's stored in my NSMutableArrays?

**The Code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    WorldClockTableViewCell *worldClockCell = (WorldClockTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
if(worldClockCell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorldClockTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    worldClockCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    /*
     Set Scrolling to OFF by default. 
     User can scroll when table is in edit mode.
     */
    [worldClockCell.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];

    // Set Digital Clock in timeLabel
    [self setDigitalClockInLabel:worldClockCell inRow:indexPath.row];

    // Set Analog Clock Carousel in ScrollView in every cell.
    [self setAnalogClocksInScrollView:worldClockCell inRow:indexPath.row];

    // Scroll to User's Preferred Clock (if this is the first launch of WorldClockTableViewController)
    if([[shouldAutoScrollArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES) {

        [self scrollToUsersPreferredClock:worldClockCell atRow:indexPath.row];
        [shouldAutoScrollArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    }   

    // Add City Name to cityLabel in every cell
    [worldClockCell buildFormattedCityName:[model.timeZoneCityNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    // Make sure new clocks created while in 'edit' mode don't scroll out of the cell
    worldClockCell.scrollView.frame = worldClockCell.scrollViewFrame;


} 

return worldClockCell;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't some of your method calls (like setting the digital clock and analog clock) be outside the if (worldClockCell == nil) block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing all your cell configuration only if it created a new cell, not if it dequeued one. Pull everything out of

```
if(worldClockCell == nil)
```

except

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorldClockTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
worldClockCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

unless you really only need to do it once, when the cell is created (and not every time it's reconfigured to display new data).

Comment: Right, I did that before, and it makes the app immensely slow. I'm guessing the problem is with the amount of views I have in my cell, correct?

Comment: how many views do you have in your cells? it's usually not too much of a problem. Maybe you could post your method implementations, to see if you're doing something really expensive. Also consider using UINib.

Comment: I have two labels, one paginated scrollview with 6 pages, and and two small imageviews. The code is all pulled from a custom class into this tableviewcontroller. I'll check out UINib.

Comment: For most scenarios, your solution would be the correct one. However, for my scenario it is not, due to the scrollViews.

Answer (score 1):

You should move all the digital and analog clocks out of the scope of check for dequeued reusable cell and all will be good. Your content is being repeated because the cell once scrolled out of view is kept for reuse.